# Getting all values of $row in csv file

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am trying this simple CSV file:

```
A;23
B;24
C;25
D;26
E;123
F;243
G;180
H;55
I;243
```

The meaning is to get an array with all values of the first column. The code looks like this:

```
<?php

    function importData($file, $store_id) {

        $handle = fopen($file, "r");

        while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) {
        $productIds = array($row[1]);
        var_dump($productIds);
        exit;

        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    importData("/home/test.csv", 3);

?>
```

When I dump the information of `$row[0]` I get the following:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
}
```

The meaning is to get all values from A to I, not only the first one. What would be necessary to apply to the code?

Thanks for your collaborations

Comment: Your call to `fgetcsv()` seems to be specifying ';' as the separator and yet your file has commas.  You also have `$row[1]` which should be the second field (0 based indexes) i.e. 23.

Comment: it's $row[0] and my csv file has semicolons, sorry for the confusion; I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the array each time. Instead initalize the array once, and then add elements using [`array_push()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) or using the [square bracket syntax](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying):

```
function importData($file, $store_id) {
    $productIds = array();

    $handle = fopen($file, "r");

    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) {
        // Append the value onto the array
        $productIds[] = $row[1];
    }
    fclose($handle);
    return $productIds;
}

$productIds = importData("/home/test.csv", 3);
```

Comment: Hi FrankerZ; I need to use $productIds inside the while loop; and when I dump it inside the while loop, I get the following:                                                                      array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C"
} and so on, which is different if I dump it outside the while loop

Comment: Well yeah...it's adding each item onto the array for each iteration. What's your issue?

Comment: Instead of adding them into the array for each iteration, the desired result should be: array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "A" } array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "B” } array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "C” }

Comment: That's 3 separate arrays, not a single result.

Comment: So you want it to return one array, that looks like this? `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
        )

)`

Comment: @Eduardo ^ Is this what you want?

Comment: the matching values from the first column will be used as input for updating the values stored in the second column; this is a reference of what I mean https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236385/issue-with-script-for-updating-products-programmatically